# How can I take down a "Scrake"?

Tags: killing-floor

I have noticed zombies with chainsaws running around the game. They seem to be passive, yet when I shoot them, they come at me and attack visiously. Is there a specific tactic I can use to take these down, or are they supposed to be this hard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrakes can be hard, but if you know how to deal with them they can be quite easy.

Your best bet, as any class, is to get the crossbow.  I buy one when I play medic solely for the purpose of killing these chainsaw-wielding mutants.  The crossbow will one-hit a Scrake if you hit in him the head, regardless of what class you are.  Since the Scrakes move slow (before you shoot them that is), getting head shots on them is a fairly simple task.

For class specifics, if you don't want the weight of carrying a crossbow to hold you down, try:

*Bezerker*:  Katana.  With the Bezerker bonus, you are able to "stun-lock" a Scrake and repetitively hit him while taking no damage from him.

*Firebug*: Any fire weapon. Flame up the Scrake a little bit, but don't pour too many shots into him, you want to keep him in his passive, walking state.  Keep backing up or killing the other mutants while the fire burns away his health.  When the fire dissipates, repeat this process.  Note: Using the flamethrower, any class can do this technique.

*Demolition*: Place a pipe bomb and get him to run over it, not sure if that kills him in one hit but it sure hurts him a ton. (I'll confirm this later tonight and edit this answer).  Or, simply unload a few shots from your M23 Grenade launcher and he'll be little pieces on the floor.

Answer (score 1):

Scrakes are supposed to be hard (although not as hard as Fleshpounds).

Best tactic is a crossbow bolt to the face (better when they are passive). It is possible to go toe-to-toe with them with a katana, but you really need to be a Berserker to get the bonus stats.

A pile of well place pipe bombs also work. As does AA12.

Generally speaking, shooting them in the head will kill them faster than not (if your aim is good enough).